# How make a Blob call private in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have a question about Azure Blob storage, whenever I make the Blob Public Access Disabled we’re unable to successfully access anything inside the container, is it anything I need to set? Like encoded call?

Comment: How are you planning to access the container ? Portal ? Code ? If code, please paste a snippet of what you have so far.

Comment: @Anupam Chand - access the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have some kind of authorization. Refer to [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal) documentation. The safest is to use Azure active directory.

Another option is to use a container level shared access signature or SAS as shown in the screenshot. The signature is signed using the storage account key and can be set to be valid for a specific period. On clicking Generate SAS, you will get a url which you can use to direct access your container. You can also have blob level SAS if needed for a specific blob.

[image]